# DC-DC Converter MOSFET Failures

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter

I've been seeing failures in a few of my circuits in which Q17 and sometimes also Q16 are failed closed in the DC-DC converter. MOSFETs used are Vishay SiHP12N50E.

Below is a schematic reference for the portion of the DC-DC Converter.

[image: partial schematic]

One avenue of troubleshooting that I've taken is looking at possible creepage/clearance or shorting issues in misassembly of the DC-DC converter. On some of the units, I found that there was continuity between various portions of the FET combinations like metal screw shorted to Q16 drain, short between metal screw, heatsink, and Q17 drain, etc. Below is the assembly reference in which you have 2 FET combos (Q14, Q15, and Q16, Q17) mounted back-to-back with a heatsink in between.

[image: assembly diagram]

Example of assembly: plastic shoulder washer -> Q17 (low side) -> thermal pad -> heatsink -> thermal pad -> Q16 (high side) -> plastic shoulder washer -> metal split washer -> metal locking washer -> metal screw (screwhead side on low side)

1. I've tried replicating the misassembly issue and while it sometimes did introduce noise, it was never at a level that the gate voltage or current ever exceeded. Am I just chasing ghost in pursuing the creepage/clearance path?
2. With the tight assembly of the pair of MOSFETs on one heatsink, am I in danger of possible arcing or leakage current that could possibly damage the FETs if creepage/clearance is an issue and some misalignment is present?

I can provide more info as needed!

Comment: The schematic is quite beautifully done. Look like something from hp or Tek documentation from the 70s. Kudos!

Comment: Long shot: the plastic shoulder at the previous job didn't fully melt but became soft enough to deform during operation, making the TO-220 loose contact with the heatsink, overheated and failed short. I've since stopped using them all together in favor of clamps as you get pressure on the middle of the body (where the heat comes from) and not the top of it (via screw).

Comment: When does failure occur, say, at startup, or after long continuous use at high power dissipation, or at sudden load change?

Comment: So these go through a sequence of tests:
1. They go through a burn-in process where its run for about 30 minutes at highest output (~340 at 300 ohm load).
2. Device is then subject to testing at or close to a direct short at the highest output setting (~25 ohms to short).

2 is where we are seeing most of our failures happen.

Comment: Is this a LLC resonant converter by any chance? C98 looks like a resonant cap to me.

Comment: H-Bridge converter!

Comment: @ShiroSan and what type of H-bridge converter is it (as questioned by Jonathon). Maybe you should show more of that circuit.

Comment: PLease add a reference to the diagrams source. (Required by site rules). In this case use seems fairly obviously legitimate BUT we still need to meet the rules requirements.

Comment: @ShiroSan - Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add the **name** and **link** of the PDF / video / webpage (whatever it was) which was the source of that image. (Or, if you copied it from a non-web source e.g. book, please add a full citation including title, author(s), page number and other info (e.g. publisher, edition etc.) if known - see the rule for details of the "best efforts".) Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. TY

Comment: I mean, since it's H-bridge and not really knowing anything more, and knowing the fact that the Drain to Source connection is a short, some things to think about could be dead-time as well as the gate drive current. On a different note, why use bidirectional TVS? It's a unipolar signal so your negative voltages would be clamped at the forward voltage of the TVS, rather than some larger clamping voltage that depends on current for a bidirectional device

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you, this was useful information and shall follow in the future! As for the source, not quite sure how to address given that this is an internal company drawing so any information there would be awesome! I can share additional information on the circuit once that is answered.

Comment: @ RogerDodger I think we've considered the dead-time given that we do tend to see some misswitching when monitoring the Gate voltage and current, but nothing crazy that would suggest damage to the FET due to overvoltage/overcurrent. The misswitching is an inherent flaw in the current design though and somewhat kept in control by the software.

As for the bidirection TVS, its actually unipolar but current schematic wasn't updated when we made some changes awhile back so sorry about the confusion!